# Spawn process, close parent and have process opened

Tags: node.js, vlc

how can I spawn a process in node.js and make it not possible to close although the parent process closes.

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;

var ex = spawn("vlc", ["/var/www/fr.mkv"]);
```

When I finish the node.js process who opened VLC, VLC closes and I don't want it to be closed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `detached` option to `true`. See [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

```
spawn("vlc", ["/var/www/fr.mkv"], { detached: true })
```